# Python error - UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment

Tags: python-3.5

The code :

```
x=0
def ex():
u= input (':  ')
if u =='a':
    print ('okay')
    x = x + 1
ex()
```

The error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    ex ()
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 5, in ex
    x = x + 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

This is what I get. I have no idea what's wrong. Thanks in advance